# I need to pass the original URI thru a mod_rewrite rule redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url:

https://myurl.com/IU/thisisastring

I need to send the entire path to my index file in the IU folder, I won't always know what the thisisastring request is.

The destination is https://myurl.com/IU/index.php

I do not need the original URI to be displayed to the user.

Another bit of information that might be useful is that this is running a process outside of a normal WordPress website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your htaccess, put this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^IU/((?!index\.php).+)$ /IU/index.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite **/IU/anystring** to **/IU/index.php?q=anystring** .

Comment: This is close, but I need to get the "thisisastring" set as a query parameter for index.php.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks!